# Removing the excerpt read more link WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I've recently installed WordPress REST API on one of my blog sites and have been using it to allow me to pull in blog posts into another static site. I have been using the following PHP to pull in the articles and their content:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('http://news.cribrater.com//wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=2');
    $posts = json_decode($json);

    foreach ($posts as $p) {

      echo '<li>';
      echo $p->featured_image ? '<figure class="wordpress-loop-bg-image" style="background: url(' . $p->featured_image->guid . ') no-repeat center; background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; ">' : '';
      echo '<figcaption><p>' . date('M j, Y', strtotime($p->date)) . '</p>  </figcaption></figure>';
      echo '<h4><a href="' . $p->link . '">'. $p->title . '</a></h4>';
      echo '' . $p->excerpt . '';
      echo '</li>';

    }

?>
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how to hide the "Read More" link that appears after the "excerpt". I can't edit the WordPress site functions file as I do need the "Read More" link for that site but would like it to be hidden on the static site.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
 .moretext {
           display: none
    }
```

Or use this functions in your functions.php and write what you want or leave empty.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Take a look in the post there are good answer: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm currently using the CSS option but have been trying to avoid loading in the "read more" link at all. The function option unfortunately isn't suited for my task as I need the text to appear on the WordPress site but not on the separate static site.

Comment: If you have other class working only in the separate site. you can write `.other-class .moretext {display: none}` in this way the class `.moretext` is hidden only in association with `.other-class`